# How do I prevent mobile visitors from visiting?

Tags: mobile, visitors

I need a script/code to prevent mobile visitors from visiting a site. Can anyone help or is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible unless you have full ownership of the client device/network (and as you use the phrase "mobile visitors", I guess that isn't the case.

Comment: I own the domain but at the moment I have a redirect on towards another site/network. They have said that they do not accept mobile optins so hence my question.